How to programmatically open whatsApp links and save messages as drafts without manual confirmation?
I've developed a cloud service (Google cloud Run job) with a webapp that responds to messages as if the replies were from me. When triggered, it reads all my emails and writes a draft as an answer. However, I want to integrate it also with WhatsApp.
I read that I can create an endpoint with the business cloud api so that the software can receive my whatsapp messages, but I realised that I can't save messages as draft with the current API. Indeed, I want to save a response generated by my service as a draft in WhatsApp, so when I open WhatsApp, the message is already there under the intended contact.
I've discovered that the "click to chat" functionality (e.g., https://wa.me/myfriendnumber?=hi) partially achieves this.
However, when I open such a link, it launches my browser first, which then prompts me to open the WhatsApp app. I'd like to bypass this manual step, avoiding the "Open in WhatsApp" confirmation popup, so that I can open multiple links programmatically and have the messages saved as drafts in WhatsApp directly.
Is there a way to automate this, or another method to achieve the same result?
